# Simple form that redirects with query string from field

Tags: javascript, django, forms, redirect, query-string

I am brushing up on my HTML while in the process of learning django and am wanting to create a form (single field and button). The button, when pushed should redirect to a page with the value in the form as a query string. For example, if the user types in "test", then pushes the button, they should be redirected to  "webpage.com?test".

Am I correct in thinking the best way to do this is with javascript? If so, would anyone mind providing an example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', function() {
    window.location.href = 'webpage.com?fieldname='
                           + document.getElementById('yourfieldid').value;
}, false);
```

since you haven't posted any code i just took the first form on the page and found a fictitious field to use as the query string parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ya, I see what you are doing and can use this to get going. Appreciate you taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the redirection directly with javascript:

```
 location.href = "webpage.com?" + your_variable
```

Or make a form that is targeted at webpage.com which has an input area named test. in this way, when it is submitted the test value will automatically be added to the url.

When you click on the button change that value and submit the form:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
 $('#your_test_field').val(your_variable);
 $('#your_form').submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href="mypage.php?arg="+variable
```